# SecKeyRef RSA pair from a seed

Tags: ios, security, encryption, rsa, public-key-encryption

I'm very noob with ObjC. I want to generate an RSA key-pair from a (random) seed just like I do in Java, is it possible in ObjectiveC (iOS) to do this?

Here is the code I use now to generate a key-pair (is the same as the CryptoExercise on the Apple documentation).

```
//here i generate the key pair
#define kPublicKeyTag           "com.apple.sample.publickey"
#define kPrivateKeyTag          "com.apple.sample.privatekey"
//i should use these as seed!?!!?
- (void)generateKeyPair:(NSUInteger)keySize {
    OSStatus sanityCheck = noErr;
    publicKeyRef = NULL;
    privateKeyRef = NULL;


    // Container dictionaries.
    NSMutableDictionary * privateKeyAttr = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    NSMutableDictionary * publicKeyAttr = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    NSMutableDictionary * keyPairAttr = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    // Set top level dictionary for the keypair.
    [keyPairAttr setObject:(id)kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA forKey:(id)kSecAttrKeyType];
    [keyPairAttr setObject:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:keySize] forKey:(id)kSecAttrKeySizeInBits];

    // Set the private key dictionary.
    [privateKeyAttr setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:(id)kSecAttrIsPermanent];
    [privateKeyAttr setObject:privateTag forKey:(id)kSecAttrApplicationTag];
    // See SecKey.h to set other flag values.

    // Set the public key dictionary.
    [publicKeyAttr setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:(id)kSecAttrIsPermanent];
    [publicKeyAttr setObject:publicTag forKey:(id)kSecAttrApplicationTag];
    // See SecKey.h to set other flag values.

    // Set attributes to top level dictionary.
    [keyPairAttr setObject:privateKeyAttr forKey:(id)@kSecPrivateKeyAttrs];
    [keyPairAttr setObject:publicKeyAttr forKey:(id)@kSecPublicKeyAttrs];

    // SecKeyGeneratePair returns the SecKeyRefs just for educational purposes.
    sanityCheck = SecKeyGeneratePair((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)keyPairAttr, &publicKeyRef, &privateKeyRef);


}
```